# Set first row to be header cells in CQ5 tableedit2 componet

Tags: aem

I am trying to create a basic table component in CQ5 and cannot seem to figure out how to format the default table to include th elements... Anyone know how to do this?

```
<tableElement
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    fieldLabel="Table"
    name="./shc:table"
    allowBlank="{Boolean}false"
    xtype="tableedit2">
    <rtePlugins jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget">
        <table features="*">
            <defaultValue header="top"/>
        </table>                                                        
    </rtePlugins>
</tableElement>
```

Just to clarify, this works but the plugin bit doesn't seem to do anything? I get a table with 3 cols and 2 rows. I need the top row to be a header (th) row by default.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a [TablePlugin](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-4/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/widgets-api/index.html?class=CUI.rte.plugins.TablePlugin) node
2. Give it a defaultValues node with a `header` property of `top`, `left` or `topleft`.

Comment: There in lies the problem, how to add a TablePlugin node. I am very new to CQ5 and the documentation does not seem to have any examples.

Comment: This should give an overview of generally configuring plugin nodes — http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-3/administering/configuring_rich_text_editor.html (On phone atm, but will try to update answer with code tomorrow)

Comment: Thanks! I've been running though that and my feature lists seem to be getting ignored :\

Comment: I wish the relevant parts of the resource were included in the answer as per SO guidelines, because the resource is 404 now.

Answer (score 0):

This may help to people in the future: 
If you click in one of the cells in a dialog, second icon from the left(cell properties) becomes available. There you can choose Cell type and set it to header then apply to entire row or column.